# Ubuntu 18.04 Which directory should my second drive be mounted in?

Tags: partitioning, 18.04, permissions, mount, hard-drive

I looked up a couple answers based on how to mount multiple drives but I don’t know the standard directory for them. Some of them say to mount them in /mnt while others say in /media while the next ones say in /home.

Where should multiple drives be truly mounted in? A second question I wanted to ask is, would it be ok to mount a drive in /home/anyfile besides this /home/username directory?

The last question I wanted to ask is, what if I want to make my multiple drives accessible to all users? How would I go about that?

Comment: There is no fixed recommendation where to mount. It can be e.g. `/media/HDD1`, `/media/HDD2`, etc. If you mount to `/media/...` disks will be shown in Nautilus.

Comment: There is no single right answer, it really depends on your use case. If it is removable drive, /media is a good place. If it is permanent then it depends on where you need more space. Or if both disks have the same characteristics, you can combine them under LVM and put '/' on resulting logical volume. Or use lobical volume for /home

Answer (score 0):

Mount in /media/[login]/NameYouWish. Disk will be shown in Nautilus side tab. Or use /mnt if showing in nautilus is not desired. You can make simlinks to home, if needed. `ln -s /media/[login]/NameYouWish/SomeFileOrFolder /home/[login]/`. Replace login with your login, and all other staff with real one.

If you mount the drive with the -o noacl option, everybody will have full read/write access. If mount with `-o ro` everybody will have read-only access. Or in /etc/fstab for mounting at boot:

```
/dev/sdb1   <desired mountpoint>  ext4 noacl 0 1
```

replace sdb1 with partition name of your drive.